# What is the difference between %reset - and reset -f in Spyder 4?

Tags: python, spyder

```
variable_one = list(1,2,3,4,5)
variable_two = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

On console
`reset -f` <-- delete all variables

But
`%reset -f` <-- the same

I do not know the difference, but the result is the same on console: delete all my variables. what difference does it make to write before '%' ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder uses Jupyter Notebook (and IPython kernel) under the hood, so what are you doing when typing and executing `%reset` is using a [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset).

Comment: it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Denis how so? it seems to answer the question just fine to me...

Comment: @starball, ok, `%reset` is the magic command. But what is it's advanatge/disavantage comparing to `reset`? What kind of magic `%` prefix adds?